# How to bake textures with no edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake a binary pattern to my surface:
[image]

However, every time I try to bake it into the texture, I end up with black edges:

[image]

So is there a way to prevent it? I bake the pattern into a 4k x 4k texture with margin of 16px. Here is the topology of the part. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What does the UV map look like? Maybe there is not enough texture space and it bleeds into the neighbor pixels?

Comment: I think this is right. It looks like your Uv islands need more space between each of them.